# Get any nth number from a string in one line command

Tags: shell, sed, command-line, grep, command

I have a string

```
indent code by 4 spaces and 6 letters and by 5 constants
```

I want to extract each number separately.

`1st number : 4`
`2nd number : 6`

The string may change, so I need a one-line command that does it.

Comment: Use: `grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 0):

Read all numbers into an array:

```
readarray -t arr < \
    <(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' \
      <<< 'indent code by 4 spaces and 6 letters and by 5 constants')
```

Now you can access all matches with their index:

```
$ echo "${arr[0]}, ${arr[1]}"
4, 6
```